# Regular expressions in JavaScript: match multiple substrings at the beginning of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build a JavaScript regular expression to match all words starting with "ad" or "ae", or all words that contain "-ad" and "-ae".

This is what I've tried:

```
var regex_string = "^[ad|ae]|-[ad|ae]";
var re = RegExp(regex_string, "i");

var matches = _.filter(data, function(r) {
  if (re.test(r)) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

However, this is matching all words beginning with 'a', 'd' or 'e'.

How can I amend the regex to match only those strings?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xGgan/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `[]` is match any letter inside So it says "match a or d or | or a or e". You need to use a capture group instead with the or.

Try

```
var regex_string = "(^(ad|ae)|-(ad|ae))";
```

Answer (score 3):

`[ ... ]` denotes a character class and anything inside will match regardless of position. Additionally, `[ae]` matches only one character, either `a` or `e`.

For what your doing, translating it directly would give:

```
(?:^(?:ad|ae)|-(?:ad|ae))
```

You use `|` in groups ( `( ... )` for capture groups and `(?: ... )` for non-capture groups; the latter are preferable if you don't intend to save captures for later use, as they improve the regex speed wise and memory wise).

But that can be optimised a bit:

```
(?:^|-)a[ed]
```

should match just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here my interpretation of "-ae AND -ad" :

```
/^(?:ad|ae)|-ad.*-ae|-ae.*-ad/
```